# Convert flex web project to flex mobile project

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4.6

I have a flex web project and I want to convert it into flex mobile project. What is the best way to do it. I know this is not recommended, however it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, because of screen size and dpi issues, using the same code will not work.

In Flash Builder, you cannot convert a web project to a mobile project.

However, in theory you can use the command line compiler tools to compile your web project code to an APK or IPA or whatever Blackberry Playbook uses.  You may have to add the libraries manually, such as SWC with all the MX libraries.

You could also create a library project, and move as much of your code as possible into the library project.  From there you can create a "web project" and a "mobile project" that share the same code/libraries.

Comment: Could you show an example (or link) of a conversion from a web project into an apk through command line tools?

Comment: Look here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c-24dc70c812b9cbf7285-8000.html

Comment: I suggest going the library project(s) route. At some point, your code for mobile/web is likely to diverge (components/skins/functionality). Create web/mobile application projects which are just "application shells" that use common code from your library project(s). Moving your existing code into the library project is easy, just drag and drop it into the library project. This will keep things organized as your code evovles :)

Answer (score 0):

In Flash builder,

1. start a new mobile project
2. copy the code to your AIR project. There should be no problem there since AS/mxml code is the same, except for application files where you need to change the root tag from Application to MobileApplication